# Columns for layout in IE9 and HTML5 (without table?)

Tags: html, user-interface, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to achieve a layout of labels and textboxes that is tabular, with straight vertical lines. Each label and textbox starting under the one above it, like this:

```
Label A    [_______]     Label B      [_______]     Label B      [_______]

Label D    [_______]     Label E      [_______]     Label F      [_______]
```

I find it very difficult to achieve this. We are targeting only IE9. I know that the table-element should be avoided for layout, but I'm running out of ideas!

Anyone with fresh ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use floated elements to achieve this.  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t0nyh0/vJYVe/9/

In that example, I've used an unordered list, but you can conceivably do it with any element as long as it has a fixed width.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myForm">
<li><label>Label A</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li><label>Label B</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li><label>Label C</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li><label>Label D</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li><label>Label E</label><input type="text" /></li>
<li><label>Label F</label><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**

```
#myForm
{
    width: 700px;
}
#myForm li
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 220px;
    float:left;
}
#myForm li label
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

​